# Can anyone tell me why I'm getting the attributeError? 'str' object has no attribute 'real'

Tags: python, attributes

```
def getFFtMag(data):
    maglist = []
    for x in range(0, len(data)):
        dataVal = data[x]
        firstVal = dataVal.real
        secondVal = dataVal.imag
        mag = math.sqrt(firstVal*firstVal + secondVal*secondVal)
        maglist.append(mag)
    return maglist

>>> getFFtMag("25 - Copy.xlsx")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    getFFtMag("25 - Copy.xlsx")
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 5, in getFFtMag
    firstVal = dataVal.real
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'real'
>>>
```

So can anyone tell me why my code is wrong?  The attached error seems to be popping up.  I'm new to python and learning what is going on.  Is the problem with my data that I inputted?  Thanks.

Comment: What is your intention by doing `dataVal.real`? And what does the error tell you?

Comment: `data[x]` must be string, you have to set it to be an `int`

Comment: Most likely your value of `data[x]` is a string, and hence has no `real` or `imag` properties. You must case the value to an integer or float first in order to access these properties. `dataVal = int(data[x])`

Comment: You need to show us the declaration of `data` because that's the variable that's throwing the error.

Comment: I think you'll be downvoted for this question like it was in [your similar previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44847613/how-do-i-calculate-fft-with-different-sets-of-data). See [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: As in your previous question, use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to iterate over a list, if you need the index and the value. Since you still only use the value, your loop could simply be `for dataVal in data:`.

Comment: @DomWeldon getFFTMag("25 - Copy.xlsx")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    getFFTMag("25 - Copy.xlsx")
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 4, in getFFTMag
    dataVal = int(data[x])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' ' I am getting this error after using your correction.  Do you know what else I can change?

Comment: Can you give us an example of your data? Is this c complex integer value?

Comment: @DomWeldon BarrelMovFFTMag
282.3210885
29.88268533
27.21032104
18.16221087
11.76253981 This data is all on column C if that changes anything.

Comment: ah, in that case `dataVal = float(data[x])` since your input is a float

Comment: @DomWeldon ValueError: could not convert string to float: I got this error after switching to a float.  I'm sorry for all these questions.  I'm still trying to learn.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to read data out of a file and not first parsing it into the complex number format. Data read out of a file will either be a string or a byte-like object depending on how you opened the file. But here, you haven't even opened the file yet.

In order to tell you how to specifically resolve this problem we will need to see the format of the file you are trying to operate on.

Comment: Is there a way I can show you the format of the file?  It's just a big excel file with data except Row 1 are strings that explain what the data in the respective columns are.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `getFFtMag` function with a string (apparently a filename) as argument. This function however requires a list (or, in general, iterable) with elements having `.real` and `.imag` attributes. Elements of a string are one-character strings, and strings don't have those attributes - complex numbers have. You need to read in contents of your file and somehow convert them to complex.

Comment: Is there a way to read in the contents of my file?  Do you know what code to use?

Comment: It might be a good idea to actually start learning the language basics. There's plenty of free tutorials online.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string to your function, and not data with a `.real` and `.imag` , and since a string does not have those fields, you get the according error.

You have to read the contents of your files first. I suggest to have a [look at pandas .read_excel() function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html)